# Check if function is true in an other class

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I've got two classes. One is main class, the other puzzle.

How to remove a child in the main class, if a function is true in the puzzle class?
I tried :

Main.as

```
if(puzzle.backToJardin = true){
stage.removeChild(target);
}
```

Puzzle.as

```
public function backToJardin(thisBack:String):void{
Engine.newBack = "jardin";
stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("changeBackground"));
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to catch "changeBackground" event in puzzle class and then call Main class code?

Comment: The problem is that it's not the only event "changeBackground" in my puzzle. I've got other function that calls the event "changeBackground". I'd like to remove the child "target" that is called in the Main.as only when the function backTojardin is true. Impossible you think ?

Comment: let's back to the beginning. what do you mean by "function is true". you know, function does not have any value, it can only return value. properties can contain values. do dou mean if function exists, or if it's return value is true. if second case, add another event thrown only if it's return value is true and catch this event.

Comment: Yes I meant "if function exists". I'll add another event. Can I add stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("functionCalled")); in Puzzle and in my main class  stage.addEventListener(functionCalled, remove) ? that'll work ?

Comment: you can check function exitence by testing 
'if ("backToJardin" in puzzle and puzzle.backToJardin is Function)'

Comment: you can add the way you want to add, but if you have more puzzles in your main stage, then you will catch event thrown at each puzzle in the same event listener, so it would be cleaner to dispach event on puzzle class, not on stageRef and catch it on particular object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to sum up for others with the same problem.

to check if object contains method or property try:

```
if ("methodOrPropertyName" in object)
```

and to chect if this is function try:

```
if( object.methodOrPropertyName is Function)
```